# select uniquely mapped genes to SNP

Tags: r, filter, code-generation, genome, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a vcf and want to select 100 genes, and for each gene, to select one SNP?
Technically if we consider one gene it has many rsid mapped to it. For my analysis I need to select 100 genes and for each gene select only one SNP for it and ignore others and have a final vcf file with only 100 genes uniquely mapped to 1 rsid only.
Is there any package which can do this?

> 22      16050075        rs587697622     A       G       100.0   PASS
> AC=1;AF=0.000199681;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=8012;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_A
> F=0.001;AA=.|||;VT=SNP;ANN=G|intergenic_region|MODIFIER|CHR_START-LA16c-4G1.3|CHR_START-ENSG00000233866|intergenic_region|CHR_START-ENSG00000233866|||n.16050 075A>G||||||  GT

This is what I am trying to do:
library(vcfR)

```
# Import VCF
my.vcf <- read.vcfR('my.vcf.gz')
# Combine CHROM thru FILTER cols + INFO cols
my.vcf.df <- cbind(as.data.frame(getFIX(my.vcf)), INFO2df(my.vcf))
data_new <- my.vcf.df[!duplicated(my.vcf.df[ ,"ANN"]),]
```

This is how my dataset looks like:
[image]

As you can see the ANN column has several ENSG00000233866 values. I want to filter the df based on ANN values that is gene ID. So for ENSG00000233866 i just want to select only one rsid or rs values and ignore others. I want to do this similarly for other genes.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and not as image such as `dput(head(mydata, 25))`? Also, how is SNP determined? Is your image 6 SNPs of one gene?

Comment: Yes, snp is determined by rsid values. So one gene can have many rsid or snp values.

Comment: Again, we are outside of your domain. Assume we know nothing. Please specify exactly where to find those IDs and want you need.

Comment: The vcf fille will have separate columns mentioning chr, position, rsid and one column name as ANN where you will find geneid. rsid means SNP. so what i need is to filter the files to just contain one rsid matched to one gene only. in this case the gene is ENSG000233866 which has many rsid values or rs324354 i just need to consider one rsid for this gene and ignore others and similarly do it for other genes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `str.split` of the pipe-delimited column in `ANN` for the *gene* which is about the fourth pipe. Then run a sequential count by the gene grouping with `ave`. Then `subset` group number for the 1. Please not below uses the new pipe, `|>` in R 4.1.0+:

```r
data_new <- within(
  data_new, {
    GENE <- gsub(
       "CHR_START-", "", 
       sapply(strsplit(ANN, "|"), "[", 4)
    )
    GENE_GROUP_SEQ <- ave(1:nrow(data_new), GENE, FUN=seq_along)
  }
) |> subset(
  GENE %in% unique(GENE)[1:100] &  # SUBSET FOR FIRST 100 GENES
  GENE_GROUP_SEQ == 1              # SUBSET FOR FIRST OF EACH GENE GROUP
) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)           # RESET ROW NAMES
```

For R versions less that 4.1.0, break out the pipe to separate calls:

```
data_new <- within(
  data_new, {
    GENE <- gsub(
       "CHR_START-", "", 
       sapply(strsplit(ANN, "|"), "[", 4)
    )
    GENE_GROUP_SEQ <- ave(1:nrow(data_new), GENE, FUN=seq_along)
  }
)

data_sub <- subset(
  data_new,
  GENE %in% unique(GENE)[1:100] &           # SUBSET FOR FIRST 100 GENES
  GENE_GROUP_SEQ == 1                       # SUBSET FOR FIRST OF EACH GENE GROUP
)

dat_sub <- `row.names<-`(data_sub, NULL)    # RESET ROW NAMES
```

Comment: I tried the above code. but it gave me an error. the error: Error: unexpected '>' in:
"  }
) |>"

Comment: Per note on last sentence, you have an older R version that does not support the new pipe, `|>`. See extended answer for earlier versions.

Comment: I tried to do the code with pipe operator. and have installed and loaded library stringr. but getting error. the error is: Error in str.split(ANN, "|") : could not find function "str.split"

Comment: Sorry. It should be `strsplit` (without period) from built-in `base` package.

Comment: yes, i edited it and it is str_split. thank you so much. it worked.